# How do I turn an array to a model input?

Tags: python, swift, keras, coreml, coremltools

I converted a keras neural network model for sequence predictions to mlmodel using the coremltools in python.

The model expects an input like [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpNQ.png),[2],[3],[4]] and gives an output of [5].
In python I would write:

> model.predict([[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpNQ.png),[2],[3],[4]])
>
> [5]

When I try to do the same in swift:

> let models = model()
>
> var array: [[Int]] = [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpNQ.png),[2],[3],[4]]
>
> print(models.prediction(input: array))

It gives me this error:

Cannot convert value of type '[[Int]]' to expected argument type 'modelInput'

I wasn't able to find anything on home to format data like mine to make it work in core ml.

Here is an image of the architecture if needed:

[image]

Finally, how do i format my own data to make it work with core ml

Comment: I am not sure if it was a typo, it needs to be `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` and it is an `[[Int]]`. I think you missed the opening `[[`

Comment: @user1046037 Yeah it's a typo sorry stackoverflow changed it to that

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your input data into 15 (!) different `MLMultiArray` objects.

The first MLMultiArray (named `lists`) is the one for your sequence. It only takes a single element.

The other 14 inputs are your LSTM hidden state variables. You need to pass these in explicitly.

To process a sequence of numbers, you have to run the Core ML model once for each element of the sequence, pass in the current hidden state each time, and read the new hidden state from the model's outputs.

It's a lot more work than in Keras. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I got a couple of questions. Why do I need 14 different inputs if I trained my input to have a size of 4 (the training array shape being (,4,1))?Where could I refer myself to find out more?

Comment: In Keras, the LSTM units themselves keep track of their internal state. In Core ML they don't and you need to manage that state. Your model has 7 LSTM units, and each unit takes two state vectors, which is 7 x 2 = 14 state vectors. You need to provide these as the inputs to the model and also grab the new state from the output of the model.

Answer (score -1):

For a single-depth array in Swift you need to set it up like:

```
var array: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
```

I don't think it's the case, but if you were trying to get a data structure where you have an "array of arrays" with each of the nested arrays being an array with a single integer member, then it'd be like:

```
var array: [[Int]] = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```